# Google Maps Autocomplete, selected option from dropdown not displaying acccurate location on first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show map when a user uses options in Autocomplete.. I am having to select a location twice for the correct map to show.. following is my code with API v3... Can anyone spot in the code below what i might be doing wrong?

```
function initializeGoogleMap() {

    //var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    //autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    //    map: map,
    //    anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    //});




    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
        zoom: 13,
        styles: [{
            //featureType: "poi",
            elementType: "labels",
            stylers: [{
                visibility: "off"
            }]
        }],
        mapTypeControl: false
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('fixturemap-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */(
        document.getElementById('txtAddress'));

    var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
    var options = {
        types: ['address']
    };

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    autocomplete.setTypes(options.types);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {

        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);

            alert("came here 1 >" + place.geometry.viewport.longitude);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
            alert("came here 2");
        }
        marker.setIcon(/** @type {google.maps.Icon} */({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
              (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
              (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.  Including any required HTML/CSS.

Comment: your code works fine for me

Comment: For `Autocomplete` please take look at this demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tCqIPbu1the6Nrm3Rgic?p=preview).

Comment: @Dr.Molle Thanks for verifying it for me, turned out that I had another function checking change of textbox and resetting Coordinates of Map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet provided above is working fine, as Dr.Molle pointed out in the comments, it led me to further investigate that there was another onChange event on the same textbox txtAddress that was resetting coordinates.

**Solution**
If someone else is facing the same issue please check your code to see if there is onChange event on the same textbox overriding the map data.

```
function initializeGoogleMap() {
 .... // Code Works Fine
}
```

[Check Working Code Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/jxr94XdGYxDscNDlvwoH?p=preview)

*PS: In my case i couldn't have posted my whole JS file as it was huge! so i could only post the main snippet handling the map.*